# Navigation Rule/Case problems

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces, jboss7.x

I created simple dynamic web project using Eclipse Juno, JSF and PrimeFaces (OS Debian). I deployed my application on JBoss AS 7.1 server (standalone). There are free pages: index, add and contact. My navigations rules are: from index to add and contact, from add to index and contact, from contact to index and add. Everythings work well but from add and contact pages I cant go to index. Index page appears only if I refresh webbrowser (Google Chrome). Has someone got the same issue? I searched it but didnt find any solutions. Thanks a lot for any help.
Here are my files:
web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

<context-param>
<param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
<param-value>excite-bike</param-value>
</context-param>
<display-name>Example2</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>add.xhtml</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>contact.xhtml</welcome-file>

</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <description>JAX-RS Tools Generated - Do not modify</description>
    <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class></servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/jaxrs/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

faces-config.xml:

```
    <managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>addBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>web.AddBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
    <managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>menuBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>web.MenuBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
    <navigation-rule>
   <from-view-id>/index.xhtml</from-view-id>
   <navigation-case>
  <from-outcome>add</from-outcome>
  <to-view-id>/add.xhtml</to-view-id>
  </navigation-case>
  <navigation-case>
  <from-outcome>contact</from-outcome>
  <to-view-id>/contact.xhtml</to-view-id>
  </navigation-case>
  </navigation-rule>
  <navigation-rule>
  <from-view-id>/add.xhtml</from-view-id>
  <navigation-case>
  <from-outcome>home</from-outcome>
  <to-view-id>/index.xhtml</to-view-id>
  </navigation-case>
  <navigation-case>
  <from-outcome>contact</from-outcome>
  <to-view-id>/contact.xhtml</to-view-id>
  </navigation-case>
 </navigation-rule>
<navigation-rule>
<from-view-id>/contact.xhtml</from-view-id>
 <navigation-case>
 <from-outcome>add</from-outcome>
 <to-view-id>/add.xhtml</to-view-id>
</navigation-case>
<navigation-case>
 <from-outcome>home</from-outcome>
 <to-view-id>/index.xhtml</to-view-id>
</navigation-case>
```

MenuBean.java:

```
package web;
import javax.annotation.ManagedBean;
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class MenuBean {
public String home(){return "home";}
public String add(){return "add";}
public String contact(){return "contact";}}
               <br>
```

code of menu in .xhtml pages:

```
<h:form>
            <p:tabMenu activeIndex="1">
                <p:menuitem value="HOME" icon="ui-icon-star"
                    action="#{menuBean.home()}" />
                <p:menuitem value="ADDS" icon="ui-icon-document"
                    action="#{menuBean.add()}" />
                <p:menuitem value="CONTACT" icon="ui-icon-person"
                    action="#{menuBean.contact()}" />

            </p:tabMenu>
        </h:form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll skip a lot of problems if you use plain links for simple navigation.

The navigation rule mechanism is more useful when used to create flows like a shopping cart, for example. Simple navigation like a menu shouldn't use the navigation rules, just make your menu a list of links, you do not need to create action methods for that.

Also, if you are using the `@ManagedBean` and `@SessionScoped` annotations in your bean you do not need to declare it in your `faces-config.xml`, the annotation is meant to replace the XML configuration. In your case, the `faces-config.xml` is actually setting up your bean to be `RequestScoped`.

**Related:**

[When should I use h:outputLink instead of h:commandLink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink)

Comment: Though your post in fact didn't answer OP's question at all, that's basically the text I would have written, so definitely +1! But I would've explained what OP did ask as well.

Comment: @skuntsel Thanks! Yeah, I thought this was a case of what the OP needed to hear, maybe not what he wanted -- feel free to edit or add your own answer so I can +1! :)